# Using Gitversiontask in VS2017 on feature gitflow branch, revision not incrementing

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, gitversion

I'm pretty new on all **AZURE devops**.

I did just the minimal install on my VS solution, nuget **Gitversiontask** in my solution, push to Azure Git pipeline and it worked with the development branch.

I created ( **GitFLOW**) a **feature** named dostuff.
Made some changes on classes, then commit & push...
Version feature/my-app 6.1.0-dostuff0001came out ...Nuget pack and push... all fine.

Then did an another commit, pipeline start but at **Nuget Push** to artifacts ...**ERROR 409** (Conflict - The feed already contains 'my-app 6.1.0-dostuff0001).

[pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5FJN.png)

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'restore WinFormExtC.sln'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: WinFormExtC/ActiveFramework.WinFormExtC.sln
    feedsToUse: config
    nugetConfigPath: NuGet/NuGet.Config

steps:
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution WinFormExtC'
  inputs:
    solution: WinFormExtC/ActiveFramework.WinFormExtC.sln
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'

steps:
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet pack WinFormExtC'
  inputs:
    command: pack
    packagesToPack: WinFormExtC/Package.nuspec
    versioningScheme: byEnvVar
    versionEnvVar: GitVersion.NuGetVersion
    includeSymbols: true

Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘Parameters.searchPatternPush’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972

steps:
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet push'
  inputs:
    command: push
    packagesToPush: '$(Parameters.searchPatternPush)'
    publishVstsFeed: '505cb4b9-0633-4d83-b4b6-1e5fc7ad020f'
```

Question: How can I get the my-app 6.1.0-dostuff0001 increase or change when I queue the pipeline in Azure devops and the build task increment the version of feature branch?

Please remember that I'm new to all this Build, yml, config etc. concept.

Comment: How did you push the packages in Azure pipeline? Could you please share your pipeline settings? (Capture screenshots for your build definition)

Comment: i added what i see as pipeline code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Why is my version not incrementing?**
>
> GitVersion calculates the semantic version, this will only change once per release. Read more at
>   [version increments](https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/v3.6.5/more-info/version-increments/)

So, to make it incremental we can set and use a config file : GitVersion.yml. Below GitVersion.yml for your reference, it works for me when trigger from master branch.

```
mode: Mainline
tag-prefix: '[vV]'
commit-message-incrementing: MergeMessageOnly
branches:
  feature:
    regex: feature?[/-]
    source-branches: ['develop']
  release:
    increment: Minor
    regex: release?[/-]
  develop:
    is-mainline: true
    increment: Patch
    regex: develop$
  master:
    regex: master$
```

More GitVersion related info please reference the following blogs:

- [Azure DevOps pipelines with YAML and GitVersion](https://ivanmilano.com/azure-devops-build-with/)
- [Effective Nuget Package Versioning in Azure DevOps with Git Tags and
  GitVersion](http://loudandabrasive.com/effective-nuget-versioning-in-azure-devops)

Comment: Thank you... i did some research.....

a) i created a file named :GitVersionConfig.yaml
   that file is in the same directory of my *.sln ( VS solution)
b) did a copy and paste of the code in section Branch configuration.
[link](https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/#branch-configuration)
in GitVersionConfig.yaml. Saved....
c) changed mode: ContinuousDelivery to mode: ContinuousDeployment for the section : feature:
Saved and when to

In AZURE Pipeline 
Edited my pipeline
 a) Nuget pack 
     Pack Option 
     SET Environment variable TO : GitVersion.FullSemVer

Comment: then 

WHEN BACK to VS included the GitVersionConfig.yaml file in my project.
did a Commit and push of all.

WHEN BACK on Azure Pipeline.
DID a save & queue.....

AND Youpie 
it WORKED 
my dll  version on feature branch increment like : 3.1.19-myfeature.39  .40  .41. ...